# why i always get unauthenticated in laravel-apidoc-generator?

Tags: php, laravel, api, generator

I'm using this package https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator to generate api documentation
but i got couple problems:

1- Running requests in the docs always return "unauthenticated" how to configure this in a right way ? i tried to add the login token to `apidoc.php` in `authorization` but it didn't work .

[image: i]

some people said i should do this 
`php artisan api:generate --actAsUserId=1` 
but it returns

```
The "--actAsUserId" option does not exist.
```

2- some request need `email` as @bodyParam but couldn't find a type of `email` so i use `text` which of course fails and return invalid type. how to force type email ?

Thanks in advance, hope i was clear.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
/**
 * @authenticated <------
 * @group MyGrupo
 * 
 */

class MyController extends Controller{
}
```

and in your console:
#php artisan apidoc:generate

Answer (score 0):

I'm a former maintainer of laravel-apidoc-generator. The package is no longer supported. Here's the one you should be using: [knuckleswtf/scribe](https://github.com/knuckleswtf/scribe).

To pass an auth value in Scribe, you set `auth.use_value` to the token in your config file. That's it. You can see more in [the docs](https://scribe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#auth).

The details in the `apply.headers` section are only used in the HTML docs, not in response calls.